# Export data in jQuery Smartwizard

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-steps, smart-wizard

This is the code used to enter information from steps 1 to 3 and display the data entered in step 4, but when entering data in step 3, the data in step 4 is not seen. Currently I am using the next part. Follow and previous buttons to save and update data in steps 1, 2, 3 and display entered data in step 4.
Note: I'm using the jQuery smart wizard library
Someone help me!!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Smart Wizard</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/smartwizard@6/dist/js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/smartwizard@6/dist/css/smart_wizard_dots.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Smart Wizard</h2>
      <div id="smartwizard">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#step-1">Bước 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#step-2">Bước 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#step-3">Bước 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#step-4">Bước 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div
            id="step-1"
            class="tab-pane"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="step-1"
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              id="inputStep1"
              placeholder="Nhập dữ liệu cho Bước 1"
            />
          </div>
          <div
            id="step-2"
            class="tab-pane"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="step-2"
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              id="inputStep2"
              placeholder="Nhập dữ liệu cho Bước 2"
            />
          </div>
          <div
            id="step-3"
            class="tab-pane"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="step-3"
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              id="inputStep3"
              placeholder="Nhập dữ liệu cho Bước 3"
            />
          </div>
          <div
            id="step-4"
            class="tab-pane"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="step-4"
          >
            <h2>Bước 4</h2>
            <div id="step4Data"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="progress">
          <div
            class="progress-bar"
            role="progressbar"
            style="width: 0%"
            aria-valuenow="0"
            aria-valuemin="0"
            aria-valuemax="100"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var selected;

          //Initialize Smart Wizard
          $("#smartwizard").smartWizard({
            selected: 0,
            theme: "arrows",
            transitionEffect: "fade",
            toolbarSettings: { toolbarPosition: "both" },
          });

          //To retrieve values of selected indexes on click of save button
          $("#save").on("click", function () {
            alert("The selected index is: " + selected);
          });

          //This code will trigger the select event of the Smart Wizard when a step is clicked
          $("#smartwizard").on(
            "showStep",
            function (e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
              selected = stepNumber; //Store the selected index
            }
          );
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm having trouble with this part and don't have a solution. I hope someone can help me rewrite it